# Splitting comma set files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file with patterns like below

```
12345343|559|-2,0,-200000,-20|20161108000000|FL|62,859,1439,1956|0,0,21300,0|S
7778880|123|500,100|20161108000000|AL|21,135|3|S
```

I'm looking for a way to separate into multiple records mapping 3rd and 6th set of values

Required output:

```
12345343|559|-2|20161108000000|FL|62|0,0,21300,0|S
12345343|559|0|20161108000000|FL|859|0,0,21300,0|S
12345343|559|-200000|20161108000000|FL|1439|0,0,21300,0|S
12345343|559|-20|20161108000000|FL|1956|0,0,21300,0|S
7778880|123|500|20161108000000|AL|21|3|S
7778880|123|100|20161108000000|AL|135|3|S
```

Comment: Have you considered hiring a programmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(.*\|.*\|)([^,]*),([^|]*)(\|.*\|.*\|)([^,]*),([^|]*)(.*)/\1\2\4\5\7\n\1\3\4\6\7/;P;D' file
```

Iteratively split the current line into pieces, building two lines separated by a newline. The first line contains the head of the 3rd and 6th fields, the second line contain the tails of the 3rd and 6th lines. Print then delete the first of the lines and then repeat till the lists in the 3rd and 6th fields are consumed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{a="";b=split($3,c,",");split($6,d,",");for(e=1;e<=b;e++){if(a)a=a RS;$3=c[e];$6=d[e];a=a$0};print a}' infile
```

Explanation :

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '    # fields are separate by | for input and output
{
a=""
b=split($3,c,",")        # split field 3 in array c
                         # b is the number of elements
split($6,d,",")          # split field 6 in array d
for(e=1;e<=b;e++)        # for each element of array c and d
    {
    if(a)                # if a is defined, append RS (\n) at the end
        a=a RS
    $3=c[e]
    $6=d[e]              # substitute fields 3 and 6 with the value of array c and d
    a=a$0                # append the complete line to a
    }
print a                  # at the end of the loop print a
}
' infile
```